# How do I center my text without creating another style

Tags: html, css

I think I'm running into CSS selector problems. I would like to center my text "Best SUV in 2015".

I'm trying to call the class rtecenter which aligns the text in the center, but it's being copied over by the original class "summary-headline" which has a text align left. I'd like to keep it text-align left because if I change it to be centered it affects other pages.

What's the best way to center align "Best SUV in 2015" without creating another style?

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/a9Lmq7pf/6/

Here's my code:

```
<div id="wrapper-landing">
    <div class="industry-intro rtecenter">
    <h3 class="summary-headline rtecenter">Best SUV in 2015</h3>
    <p>When it comes to safety the 2015 Subaru Forester simply runs over the competition.

</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
#wrapper-landing {
width: 916px;
margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
padding: 0;
```

}

```
.industry-intro,.landing-intro {
    margin: 0 30px 0 30px;
}

#wrapper-landing p {
    color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
    font-family: 'SegoeRegular',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}

    h3.summary-headline {
        color: #2251a4;
        font-family: SegoeBold, Helvetica, Arial;
        font-size: 26px;
        line-height: 34px;
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
        text-align: left;
    }

.rtecenter {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can remove the `h3` from `h3.summary-headline`, that will allow `.rtecenter`'s text-align declaration to override the value from `.summary-headline`.

i.e.:

```
.summary-headline {
    color: #2251a4;
    font-family: SegoeBold, Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 34px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    text-align: left;
}

.rtecenter {
    text-align: center;
}
```

The specificity of the `h3.summary-headline` (which applies to the tag AND the class combination) is greater than a declaration that just applies to a class, so that is why `text-align: left` is winning out over `text-align: center`. There is a very useful guide to CSS selector specificity at CSS Tricks: [Specifics of CSS Specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

Comment: +1, Shouldn't your code block have `.summary-headline` ?

Comment: you forgot to remove the `h3` from the selctor in your code.

Comment: I voted this answer because it works `"without creating another style"`

Answer (score 0):

You basically just need higher specificity:

So you can add this CSS style:

```
h3.rtecenter {
    text-align: center;
}
```

or

```
.summary-headline.rtecenter {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Whichever fits your layout better.

http://jsfiddle.net/biz79/a9Lmq7pf/14/

Answer (score 0):

`h3.summary-headline` is more specific than `.rtecenter` because it specifies an element and a class (which is more specific than just a class). You could make it equally as specific by adding the `h3.summary-headline` selector, and further override it by adding `.rtecenter`:

```
.rtecenter,
h3.summary-headline.rtecenter {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specificity determines, which CSS rule is applied by the browsers: !important > inline style > ID > Pseudo-class > Attribute selector > Class > Type > Universal

As of now h3.summary-headline has a higher specificity than .rtecenter so it will take priority. 
if you take remove the h3 specification from .summary-headline, .rtecenter will take priority as it's position is your css document is lower.